# Conditional SQL ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I've got a polymorphic table that needs to be ordered, but the column to use for ordering depends on the `type` field of the table.  Something like this:

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN type=FOO THEN (table.last_name, table.first_name) ELSE table.name END`

However, this doesn't work, can anybody point me in the right direction, I'm trying to say (in psuedocode)

`IF type is FOO sort by last_name, first_name ASC OTHERWISE sort by name ASC`

Comment: Did you mean to concatenate this?: `(table.last_name, table.first_name)`

Comment: No, I want them ordered by last_name then first_name.

Comment: You are conditionally asking to order by two fields _or_ one. That will not work.

Comment: Can you try ORDER BY ISNULL(table.name, table.last_name+table.first_name)?

Comment: `... ORDER BY CASE WHEN type=FOO THEN (table.last_name, table.first_name) ELSE (table.name, null::text) END;` The ordering over the row type works well as I know (never tried it, sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you need a case for each column

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN type=FOO THEN (table.last_name)  ELSE table.name END, 
         CASE WHEN type=FOO THEN (table.first_name)  ELSE null END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify it with two fields:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN type=FOO THEN table.last_name ELSE table.name END,
   CASE WHEN type=FOO THEN table.first_name ELSE '' END
```